# Is there a share code for this Aim Arena/Sniper's Alley custom game?

Tags: overwatch

[image: Screenshot of unknown custom game down length of map corridor]

Does anyone have and can generate a share code for the sort of Aim Arena custom game seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iwrKO_526Y)?

The map must be from the [Sniper's Alley](https://workshop.elohell.gg/zQU0dA9vNHAJ1f5/Sniper%27s+Alley+(A+Workshop+Only+Map)/) (share code NA900) custom game.

Differences/key features:

- Damage dealt HUD
- Choice of hero
- Instant respawn

Currently I play on share code XAFPE. It's my balanced version of [Aim Arena Z v3.3 by Gantz](https://workshop.codes/59FF9) (59FF9). AA Z v3.3 has choice of hero and instant respawn but not the other features.